# TypeError: fn is not a function

Tags: discord.js

```
case 'mute':
            var person  = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.roles.cache.find()(args[1]));
            if(!person) return message.reply("That player doesn't exist!");

            let mainrole = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Verified");
            let role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Mute");

            if(!muterole) return message.reply("Couldn't find the mute role.");

            let time = args[2];

            if(!time){
                return message.reply("Please didnt specify a time!");
            }

            person.roles.add(mainrole.id)
            person.roles.remove(role.id);

            message.channel.send(`@${person.user.tag} has now been muted for ${ms(ms(time))}`)
           
            setTimeout(function(){

                person.roles.add(mainrole.id)
                person.roles.remove(role.id);
                console.log(role.id)
                message.channel.send(`@${person.user.tag} has been unmuted!`)
            }, ms(time));
            break;
        }
});
```

is my code.

> TypeError: fn is not a function
> at Client. (C:\Users\nippo\Desktop\aniGuesser\index.js:64:112)
> at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
> at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\nippo\Desktop\aniGuesser\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
> at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\nippo\Desktop\aniGuesser\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
> at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\nippo\Desktop\aniGuesser\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
> at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\nippo\Desktop\aniGuesser\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
> at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\nippo\Desktop\aniGuesser\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
> at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\nippo\Desktop\aniGuesser\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
> at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
> PS C:\Users\nippo\Desktop\aniGuesser> node .
> aniGuesser Is Online. Bring the Cake!
> C:\Users\nippo\Desktop\aniGuesser\node_modules@discordjs\collection\dist\index.js:160
> if (fn(val, key, this)) the error thingy.

I decided to start making a bot so my friends think im smart so i started watching a youtube series on how to configure these bots. In the process i decided to make a mute command cuz why not but then i got this error. before this i had "message.guild.roles.get" and the comments told me to change it to message.guild.roles.cache.find  although that resolved my problem, i have this error now. btw
even when i use the paste bin and only changing the words around it still has this error.

Comment: From the stack trace (the errors), it looks like on line 64 of your code you have a function called `fn` that wasn't defined before. What does that look like?

Comment: i dont understand what u mean by, a function called fn. I dont know if that means much  but the only line changed was the ; at the of line 64, which did absolutely nothing.

Comment: It seems like you're calling something called `fn` as if it were a function. That would look something like this `fn()`, similar to what you're doing when you call `console.log()`. The problem is coming from you calling `fn` without it actually being a function. Is `fn` defined earlier in your code?

Comment: When i get rid of .find and replace it with .get it says this: https://pastebin.com/tJh4Us0Y

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include line 64? The code you have provided does not show where the error or `fn` came from.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this: `message.guild.roles.cache.find()(args[1]));`.

First, `find` takes a function, (which causes the error shown).

Second, you're trying to call the value returned by `find` which would be a role and not a function `find()(args[1])`, but I assume this was a typo and you meant to use this to add a function.